# Upload directly to Dropbox

Tags: sync, dropbox, upload

We have a NAS which contains around 600GB of files which we want to upload to Dropbox. The only problem is that our Dropbox folder is located on our local computer which has only got 500GB of storage. Obviously, we cannot drop the files into the Dropbox folder to upload it, is there a way we can upload directly?

Once the files are there, we don't necessarily need to keep it synced.. just backed up.

We tried dragging the folder into Dropbox.com, but that can only deal with 3000 files at a time and would mean that Chrome would need to be kept open and not accidently closed (which happens often).

Comment: Just setup the Dropbox directory on the NAS.

Comment: Which OS? If on Linux, mount the NAS in the DropBox folder

Comment: It's on Windows.The dropbox folder has already got 300GB of files in it, so moving it will mean Dropbox will have to reindex them

Comment: Dropbox isn't a hosting service, so you will have to keep a local copy of the files for it to sync with.

Comment: I would recommend a different service than Dropbox. Amazon S3 is designed for long-term, reliable storage. You will have to upload it through a client, though. I recommend Cloud Berry. I have done about 50GB at a time without an issue.

Comment: This issue still exists as of Sept. 2014, and I'd love an answer.  In my case, my Dropbox folder is on my 100GB laptop HD and I have 200GB on an external drive that I'd like to upload to my Dropbox account (without syncing it to the laptop, obviously).  My way around this was to de-sync my laptop HD, create a new Dropbox folder on my external HD, sync that, drop the files in there, unsync the external HD, and then re-sync the laptop HD (with selective sync enabled).  Not pretty, but it got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload it directly (without moving or copying it to the local Dropbox folder) you can try Boxifier (http://www.boxifier.com), which is a free app that I wrote.

It works on top of the Dropbox client to help you sync any folder outside of your Dropbox folder, including those on network drives. You will still need the Dropbox client to be installed on your computer.

Just right-click the folder on the NAS to make Boxifier sync it with Dropbox.

[image]